# Magento1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue

Tags: passwords, magento-1.9.1

I am encountering this issue in CE1.9.1.

When a User registers (doesn't matter if its during checkout or from the Create an Account link) the user keeps getting the password mismatch error even though the password is re-entered correctly.

The form validation does not indicate a miss-match, but once a user clicks on Register it returns the mismatch error.

There is no errors in the chrome console...

I found this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/please-make-sure-your-passwords-match-password-error-in-checkout-with-new-re

But I don't believe it is the same error.

I need to fix it soon, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We also had this issue with 1 of our webshops. However we used a checkout extension. So im not sure if this applies for the regular standard checkout. Anyway.

The question should be, are u using a checkout extension?

If so, the value inside the model's file of that extension is set at:

```
 $customer->setConfirmation($password);
```

but should be:

```
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($password);
```

For me this worked, without changing anything in the core. It's just that the extensions should get a small update, or you can do it manually like i did. Just find that line in the files of the model map of your extension.

Comment: This solved my problems with the IWD Social Login extension. Thanks.

Comment: Wow sorry for the delay in responding. 
We did used a checkout extension, if I remember correctly our original solution was exactly this as well.

Answer (score 2):

as workaround you can use folloing code:

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
$passwordconfirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
//if ($password != $confirmation) {
if (!(($password == $confirmation) ||
    ($password == $passwordconfirmation))) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
}
```

Comment: Did you mean  
`if (!(($password == $confirmation) || !($password == $passwordconfirmation))) {`? I assume your change should go to customer.php.

Answer (score 1):

Changing app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php as proposed by @Pedro breaks the functionality of "forgot password" and "edit customer account" pages. Instead, make the following changes to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```

by editing lines starting from 369

```
if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == self::METHOD_REGISTER) {
  // set customer password
  $customer->setPassword($customerRequest->getParam('customer_password'));
  $customer->setConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password'));
} else {
  // emulate customer password for quest
  $password = $customer->generatePassword();
  $customer->setPassword($password);
  $customer->setConfirmation($password);
}
```

and set the PasswordConfirmation -Property and not the Confirmation-Property of the Customer-Object:

```
if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == self::METHOD_REGISTER) {
  // set customer password
  $customer->setPassword($customerRequest->getParam('customer_password'));
  $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password'));
} else {
  // emulate customer password for quest
  $password = $customer->generatePassword();
  $customer->setPassword($password);
  $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($password);
}
```

Comment: Also facing that problem. To my surprise, the above code snippet starts at line 398 and contain already the `setPasswordConfirmation` property followed by `setGroupId` call as last line in the `else` statement. I updated from 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.1.0. Changing the code like Pedro mentioned below works for the registration, but as soon as I check out as a guest I get a password mismatch alert popup when finished the address checkout step. Very confused about that, either I miss something or there is something else quiet not right ... Time is short as the customer wants to go live with his store.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem and fixed it. Snel's answer is closer to right answer. The problem could lay in the external/local modules, so you should check not the

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```

And of course do NOT modify it in any case!
But you should find _validateCustomerData() method which is used in your case. Use Mage::log() or debug_backtrace() for it. It may look something like (but not exactly, because this part could be modified for some reason):

```
if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == self::METHOD_REGISTER) {
  // set customer password
  $customer->setPassword($customerRequest->getParam('customer_password'));
  $customer->setConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password'));
} else {
  // emulate customer password for quest
  $password = $customer->generatePassword();
  $customer->setPassword($password);
  $customer->setConfirmation($password);
}
```

Those modules extend the old version of core file so if you module wasn't updated, you should change them yourself and change

```
setConfirmation()
```

to its current usable analog:

```
setPasswordConfirmation()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem. I'm not comfortable with code so I wanted to avoid all the above fiddling. To fix it all I did was update my extensions, and I also disable one page checkout, cleared cache, then re-enabled one-page checkout.

This has now fixed the problem without needing to modify code.

hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this truly is a core bug, I wouldn't recommend changing core files.But i sloved this way Open app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php and edit your code like below

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
$passwordconfirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
//if ($password != $confirmation) {
if (!(($password == $confirmation) ||
    ($password == $passwordconfirmation))) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still can't figure out, why this is happening:
The Conlabz Useroptin extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-double-opt-in-for-customers.html) can cause this behavior aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to 1.9.2.1 and was unable to resolve using some of the suggested code changes here and elsewhere - also very reluctant to change core code for obvious reasons.

My solution - a configuration update. It was:

- Enable OnePage Checkout = Yes
- Allow Guest Checkout = Yes
- Require Customer to be Logged in = No

I updated to Yes/No/Yes as per the above and cleared the cache. This resolved the issue by inserting the standard customer registration form (rather than appending the registration to end of the billing info) and passing that info to the billing form on successful registration.

It seems there is a code issue here along the lines of the other responses but this was an excellent workaround for me. Hope it helps.

[image: Checkout Configuration Settings]

Answer (score -1):

Change this code

```
app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

to this code

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```