# Magento CE1.9.2.0 Passwords do not match fixed yet other functions get broken

Tags: php, magento, passwords

The title might me a little confusing but I'm not sure how to explain it in a short sentence.

**Overview**

Magento CE1.9.2.0 (1.9.1.0 might aswell) has a little bit of a bug in it.
Whenever someone wants to register on my website, and inserts their password and confirmation password, it says "Please be sure the passwords match" (Something in that direction, mine is Dutch).
This is questioned quite alot on SO. Yet it still doesn't really have a clear and whole fix. 
(For me atleast)

**Related questions**

I have seen quite some questions about this:

1. [CE1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue during User registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46404/ce1-9-1-please-make-sure-your-password-match-issue-during-user-registration)
2. [Magento 1.9 Checkout Registration Password Match Issue [duplicate]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/magento-1-9-checkout-registration-password-match-issue)
3. [Magento1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311240/magento1-9-1-please-make-sure-your-password-match-issue)

**What have I tried?**

In `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` I have tried to change the following code (Around line: 844):

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

To:

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```

This DID fix my problem on the registration page. Yet, this broke my checkout form.
Now when I want to order something, and I fill in the form on the checkout (Name, Address etc.) it says that the "Passwords don't match", AND it says that the address and Phone number aren't present.

So I've tried to fix this by going to: 
`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php`

And changing this (Around line: 429):

```
$customer>setPasswordConfirmation($customerRequest>getParam('confirm_password');
```

To this:

```
$customer>setConfirmation($customerRequest>getParam('confirm_password'));
```

And this **might have** fixed the "Password don't match" on the checkout page.

**Conclusion**

*Now the only issue I'm facing is that the checkout page says that I need to check my address information and phone number.*

Is there anything that will fix this issue? Anything that is better?
Did I do something wrong in the code?